# using dependency injection to return a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, dependency-injection, return

Is there a way to return a function in javascript without calling it, but still specifying parameters? I'm working on a simple imitation of angular's dependency injection system in javascript using node.js--the inject() method is called like this:

```
var injectedFunction = module.inject(function (funcToRegister) {
  return funcToRegister();
});
```

And the module.inject() function looks like this:

```
var inject = function(func) {    
    var args = resolveDependencies(func);
    // so 'args' is an array of function dependencies, like [Function: funcToRegister]
    return func.apply(null,args);
    // not sure how to correctly return this function!
  };
```

Currently I can't figure out how to return the function with its updated dependencies (as arguments) without actually calling it, or just returning a null object. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `apply` you can use `bind` which partially applies the function, and returns it (it does not execute it):

```
return func.bind.apply(func, [null].concat(args))
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I'm not super versed in javascript so this would've taken me forever to find. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
var inject = function(func) {    
    var args = resolveDependencies(func);
    // so 'args' is an array of function dependencies, like [Function: funcToRegister]
    return func.bind(null,args);
    // not sure how to correctly return this function!
};
```

[Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)